# Can I perform Generalized Iterative Scaling in R?

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining

I'm looking to port our home-grown platform of various machine learning algorithms from C# to a more robust data mining platform such as R. While it's obvious R is great at many types of data mining tasks, it is not clear to me if it can be used for text classification.

Specifically, we extract a list of bigrams from the text and then classify it into one of 15 different categories, eg:

Bigram list: jewelry, books, watches, shoes, department store
-> Category: Shopping

We'd want to both train the models in R as well as hook up to a database to perform this on a larger scale.

Can it be done in R?

Comment: This paper might be of interest to you. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  The title mentions a general methodology, while the text of the question is not particularly informative about the models you're trying to investigate.  The answer is yes, R can be used for text classification.  Please give more specifics on your goal.

Comment: Sure thing. There are many different types of classification problems we'd like to solve, but a simple example of one would be load in a set of documents and assign them to one of 15 different categories. Depending on the algorithm chosen, a document may be preprocessed into different forms, such as A) a simple text file B) a bag of unigrams C) a bag on bigrams, etc. It seems likely that a GIS approach on a bigram list would work well, but classification trees also seem like a promising candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I am rather starting to look into Machine Learning, but I might have a suggestion: have you considered [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)? There's a bunch of various algorithms around and there'S IS some documentation. Plus, there is an R package `RWeka` that makes use of the Weka jars.

EDIT: 
There is also a nice, comprehensive read by Witten et al. : [Data mining](http://www.amazon.de/Data-Mining-Practical-Techniques-Management/dp/0123748569/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1320310991&sr=8-1) that contains an extensive description of Weka among other interesting things. Look into the API opportunities.

Comment: We don't use Java but it might be something to consider if R doesn't work.

Comment: Don't need to be too much into Java to try RWeka. Just install.packages("RWeka") and a little browsing the vignette will do.

Comment: Nice... I didn't know that. I will look into it some more then!